# Failed to get yarn configuration while installing Jupyter Lab in Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, jupyter, hadoop-yarn, jupyter-lab

I am trying to install some extensions for jupyterlab in Cygwin. So I type, for example, `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` in the Cygwin command prompt. But I get an error. Here's the log:

```
Fail to get yarn configuration. internal/module/cjs/loader.js:968
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\home\<user>\<path_to_venv>\lib\python3.8\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND,
  requireStack: []
}

Fail to get yarn configuration. internal/module/cjs/loader.js:968
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\home\<user>\<path_to_venv>\lib\python3.8\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND,
  requireStack: []
}

An error occured.
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/tmp/tm1da390j3'
See the log file for details: /tmp/jupyterlab-debug-mgr2ux9k.log
```

I understand the error: instead of looking for `C:\cygwin64\home\<user>\<path_to_venv>\lib\python3.8\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js` the installation manager looks for `C:\home\<user>\<path_to_venv>\lib\python3.8\site-packages\jupyterlab\staging\yarn.js`. I just don't know how to fix it. Maybe I need to edit some configuration files. I would be very grateful for your help.